# RequireJS and AngularJS multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angularjs-controller

I'm using latest version of Require and Angular, but i encountered strange bug. I have controller for every view, but apparently works only for one view. This is my example code:

**Define all controllers: Controllers.js**

```
define([
   'modules/index/controller',
   'modules/test/controller'
], function(){});
```

Here works only with one controller, if i include 2 like here i get *Error: ng:areq
Bad Argument*

**Index: controller.js**

```
define(['angular'], function(angular){

   'use strict';

   return angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])

   .controller('indexCtrl', ['$scope' , function ($scope){
        alert("index ok");
   }]);

});
```

**Test: controller.js**

```
define(['angular'], function(angular){

   'use strict';

   return angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])

   .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope' , function ($scope){
    alert("test ok");
    }])

});
```

Where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating the `myApp.controllers` module twice and one is overwriting the other.  Assuming that you are manually bootstrapping angular after loading the controller, what you should be doing is to create the module first, then load that module to create controller:

**app.js**

```
define(['angular'], function(){
   'use strict';
   return angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
});
```

**Index: controller.js**

```
define(['app'], function(app){
   'use strict';
   return app.controller('indexCtrl', ['$scope' , function ($scope){
        alert("index ok");
   }]);
});
```

**Test: controller.js**

```
define(['app'], function(app){
   'use strict';
   return app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope' , function ($scope){
    alert("test ok");
    }])
});
```

I created `angularAMD` to facilitate use of RequreJS and AngularJS that might be of interest to you:

http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/